# Return same view controller using ModelAndView of Spring Web MVC

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Web MVC and Hibernate for developing my application.

My login.jsp page has following code :

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="User">
   User Name : 
      <form:input path="email"/>
   Password : 
     <form:input path="password"/>

<input type="submit" align="center" value="Execute">
```

Now, My servlet.xml file has following code :

```
 <bean name="/uservalidate.htm" class="com.sufalam.mailserver.presentation.web.UserValidateFormController">
        <property name="sessionForm" value="true"/>
        <property name="commandName" value="User"/>
        <property name="commandClass" value="com.sufalam.mailserver.bean.User"/>
        <property name="formView" value="login"/>
        <property name="successView" value="layout.jsp"/>
        <property name="userSecurityProcessor" ref="IUserSecurityProcessor"/>
    </bean>
```

My UserValidateFormController has following code :

```
public class UserValidateFormController extends SimpleFormController {

    /** Logger for this class and subclasses */
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    private IUserSecurityProcessor userSecurityProcessor;

    public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command)
            throws ServletException, SufalamException {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            Map model = new HashMap();


        String username = ((User) command).getEmail();
        String password = ((User) command).getPassword();
        List userChecking = new ArrayList();
        userChecking = userSecurityProcessor.findByAll(username, password, 0.0);
        System.out.println("userChecking length = "+userChecking.size());
        if (userChecking.size() == 1) {
            return new ModelAndView("layout");
            //return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
        }

        return new ModelAndView("login", model);

    }

    protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        User user = new User();
        return user;
    }

  public void setUserSecurityProcessor(IUserSecurityProcessor userSecurityProcessor) {
        this.userSecurityProcessor = userSecurityProcessor;

    }
```

In my UserValidateFormController at the time of handing submit event, i am checking that username and password are correct or not..

It's working fine & if both are matching then its redirecting to layout.jsp, that's also fine.

But if username or password are incorrect then i want to redirect to same login.jsp page and display appropriate error..

Please suggest me the solution that what to do redirecting to same view controller..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: ... if you don't mind asking, if you've gone to the trouble of using Spring, is there particular reason why you're rolling your own security measure instead of implementing Acegi ( or Sprint Security as it's called now) ?

Comment: Ya, i have used ACEGI and very well known about it... But, my current system doesn't requires that much of load.. This questions is just of the basic spring concepts that how can i redirect to same called JSP page, controller..

Comment: @vector: Spring Security is a bit of a monster, and for simple tasks it's often more trouble than it's worth

Comment: Every time someone uses `SimpleFormController`, the little baby jesus cries....

Comment: Did you solve this? Please post the solution if so...

Comment: @ria I have posted my own answer with solution... Have a look on it..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally solve this issue with following line of code :

```
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
```

or

```
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("success.htm");
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

If you have an [InternalResourceViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html) configured, you can do it like this:

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:success.htm");
```

In my opinion, this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

... not sure if this is what you're looking for, but is this how I solve your problem:

```
    else { return new ModelAndView( "login", model ); }
```

... otherwise I missed something in your question. It seems to me you're pretty far to get stuck like this.

Comment: I can't do that, as my login page requires User to be initialized... So, it will be in trouble and give me an error of can't find User Command from login.jsp..

Comment: ... then what about: return new ModelAndView( new RedirectView ( getFormView() ), model );

Answer (score 0):

I would say all you have to do is populate your model before using it again:

```
    if (userChecking.size() == 1) {
        return new ModelAndView("layout");
        //return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
    }
    model.put("User", command);
    return new ModelAndView("login", model);
```